# cartopy conda install error osx: Library not loaded: @rpath/libproj.0.dylib

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, cartopy

Did conda install:

```
conda install -c scitools cartopy
```

Seemed to go find, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-762e43a32730>", line 1, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs

  File "/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs

  File "/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 37, in <module>
    from cartopy._crs import CRS, Geocentric, Geodetic, Globe, PROJ4_RELEASE

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/_crs.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libproj.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/_crs.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any suggestions?

I also tried building from source and got the same problem.

I had a prior install of GDAL Complete, if that matters.

Comment: Similar question asked at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scitools-iris/97bLdmbwomw with no solution as yet. I suspect the proj4 version has moved on from that expected by cartopy, though am by no means certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an actual bug in program: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/617